# sql server 2012 mail setup on windows azure cloud vm

Tags: email, azure, cloud, sql-server-2012, virtual-machine

I am setting up the email option on sql server 2012 in a windows azure cloud Virtual Machine. The email is not working and im getting the following error :

> Error,15,The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 2
>   (2012-07-02T11:13:17).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail
>   server. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.).),3152,5,,7/2/2012 11:13:17 AM,sa
>   07/02/2012 11:12:05,,Error,14,The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using
>   Account 2 (2012-07-02T11:12:05).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails
>   to mail server. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the
>   validation procedure.)

Should I have an end point 25 on my vm ? What else could cause this error ?

Comment: Can you explain the setup? Is the mail server set up on the machine locally or are you trying to route mail to an external SMTP server? Is your SMTP server configured to use IPv6 (IPv4 is not an option)? [This troubleshooting article might be useful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with the outbound stmp server you are trying to use. Is this also hosted in Windows Azure or an external provider somewhere? In both cases, make sure they allow inbound, authenticated connections and on what port. There shouldn't be any blocks on outbound connections on your Windows Azure virtual machine, so odds are the problem is where the email server is hosted.

Comment: It is an external smtp server.

Comment: I had to untick the SSL thick box. All is working now. Thanks peeps